# Case used in integer values

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
LocationID  LocationName
50          Sharjah
51          Qatar
55          Rigga
6           Dubai Mall
```

I need to make sql query that takes `locationId` as parameter,
if `locationId` is passed 0 then I want to show all this records otherwise show as per `locationId` passed.
I tried case statement but not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Here `@Parm` will be passing value to your script

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE (@Parm = 0 OR LocationID = @Parm)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @locationId INT;

SELECT LocationID, LocationName
FROM yourTable
WHERE @locationId = 0 OR LocationID = @locationId
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stored proc for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #LOCATIONS
(
    LocationID  INT
    ,LocationName VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO #LOCATIONS VALUES(
50,'Sharjah')
,(51,'Qatar')
,(55,'Rigga')
,(6,'Dubai Mall')

SELECT * FROM #LOCATIONS
GO

CREATE PROC LOC ( @LOC_ID INT )
AS
BEGIN

    IF(@LOC_ID = 0)
        SELECT * FROM #LOCATIONS
    ELSE

    SELECT * FROM #LOCATIONS WHERE LocationID = @LOC_ID
END
GO

EXEC LOC 0 -- Try Executing the stored proc like this
EXEC LOC 55 -- Try Executing the stored proc like this
```